# Do not why Array not storing numbers in java

Tags: java

hi im a beginner in java i am trying to write a program that records the value of three dice rolls in a game between two players. i have to utilise arrays. the problem is that when i print out to screen for some reason the value of each dice is 0 and it is not printing the randomly generated roll. the idea is when we print to screen it should say round 1 player 1: and display each number rolled on the three dice and then do a calculation and output the points dependant on weather they are three the same or all different etc.
This is what i have so far any help would be appreciated as i am a beginner and have been trying to figure this out for hours.

This is the first class

// Description:     program to simulate two players each rolling three dice for a number of rounds

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dicegame   {

static Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)  {

int[] num = new int[3];
int numberOfRounds;
numberOfRounds = 0;
do {
//This will print out a request for the user
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of rounds: \n");
//This will ensure the input value will remain above 0
    numberOfRounds = read.nextInt(); } while (numberOfRounds < 1);

    Dicegame2 Dicegame2Object = new Dicegame2(numberOfRounds);
    //This is instantiating the scanner object
    Dicegame1 Dicegame1Object = new Dicegame1(num[0], num[1], num[2]);

    Dicegame1Object.order();
    Dicegame2Object.diceValue();

    for(int round=0;round<numberOfRounds;round++){
        System.out.println("Round "+ (round+1)
        +" Player1: "+ num[0]+num[1]+num[2]+
        " Points: ");   }

    if(Dicegame1Object.threeAllTheSame()){
        System.out.print(Dicegame2Object.sumOfDiceSame());;
    }else{
        if(Dicegame1Object.alInOrder()){
            System.out.print(Dicegame2Object.sumOfDiceRun());
        }else{
            if(Dicegame1Object.twoSameOneDifferent()){
                System.out.print(Dicegame2Object.sumOfDiceDifferent());
            }else{
                System.out.print(Dicegame2Object.sumOfDicePair());
            }
        }
    }
}   

}
```

This is the second class

// Description:     program to simulate two players each rolling three dice for a number of rounds

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dicegame1  {
//variables
private int Dice1;
private int Dice2;
private int Dice3;

    int[] num = new int[3];
private final int numberOfThrows = 3;

                    //Constructor
public Dicegame1 (int D1, int D2, int D3)

//This is assigning local variables to class variables

{   num[0] = D1;
    num[1] = D2;
    num[2] = D3;
}

//This will calculate to see if the dice are all the same
//This is a boolean method which contains an if statement   
    public boolean threeAllTheSame(){
        boolean trueOrNot;
        if((num[0] == num[1])&&(num[1]==num[2])){
                trueOrNot = true;
        }else{
                trueOrNot = false;
            }
        return trueOrNot;
}

//This will calculate to see if the dice are a pair
//This is a boolean method which contains an if statement
    public boolean twoSameOneDifferent(){
        boolean trueOrNot;
        if  (((num[0] == num[1])&&(num[1]!=num[2]))||
            ((num[1] == num[2])&&(num[2]!=num[0]))||
            ((num[0] == num[2])&&(num[0]!=num[1]))){
                trueOrNot = true;
        }else{
                trueOrNot = false;
            }
        return trueOrNot;
}

//This will calculate to see if the roll is a run
//This is a boolean method which contains an if statement
    public boolean alInOrder(){
        boolean trueOrNot;
        if  ((num[1] == (num[0]+1))&&
            (num[2] == (num[1]+1))){
                trueOrNot = true;
        }else{
                trueOrNot = false;
            }
        return trueOrNot;

    }

//This will calculate to see if the dice are all different  
//This is a boolean method which contains an if statement  
    public boolean allDifferent(){
        boolean trueOrNot;
        if  ((num[0] != (num[1]))&&(num[1] != (num[2]))&&(num[2] !=    (num[0]))){
                trueOrNot = true;
        }else{
                trueOrNot = false;
        }
        return trueOrNot;
    }


//This will sort out the numbers of the array in order  
    public void order(){
        Arrays.sort(num);
    }

    }
```

This is the third and final class

// Description:     program to simulate two players each rolling three dice for a number of rounds

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dicegame2  {

//variables
private int numberOfRounds;
private int Dice1;
private int Dice2;
private int Dice3;
private Dicegame1[] match;

//constructor
public Dicegame2(int nOfRounds) {

    numberOfRounds = nOfRounds;
    match = new Dicegame1 [numberOfRounds];

}
    public void diceValue() {
        int[] num = new int[3];
        for(int i=1;i<numberOfRounds;i++){
            Dice1 = 1+(int)(6*Math.random());
            Dice2 = 1+(int)(6*Math.random());
            Dice3 = 1+(int)(6*Math.random());
            match [i] = new Dicegame1(num[0], num[1], num[2]);
        }   

}

//This will calculate the sum of dice if all the same       
    public int sumOfDiceSame(){
        int calc1;
        int[] num = new int[3];
        calc1 =((num[0]+num[1]+num[2])+60);
        return calc1;
    }
 //This will calculate the sum of dice if its a pair
    public int sumOfDicePair(){
        int calc2;
        int[] num = new int[3];
        calc2 =((num[0]+num[1]+num[2])+20);
        return calc2;
    }
//This will calculate the sum of dice if its a run
    public int sumOfDiceRun(){
        int calc3;
        int[] num = new int[3];
        calc3 =((num[0]+num[1]+num[2])+40);
        return calc3;
    }       
 //This will calculate the sum of dice if all different
    public int sumOfDiceDifferent(){
        int calc4;
        int[] num = new int[3];
        calc4 =(num[0]+num[1]+num[2]);
        return calc4;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://sscce.org/

Comment: `new Dicegame1(num[0], num[1], num[2]);` : the values are passed into the Dicegame1, which cannot change `num` as Java has no outpput parameters / call by reference. Only if you pass `num` you could change `num[0]` etcetera.

Comment: i dont understand how i pass num. Not sure what you mean to be honest

Answer (score 0):

As I was able to see into your code, you are printing the array of nums into your main, that are not set.

Second that array is not needed at all.

You have something like Dicegame2. From what I am seeing I would create additional method here that will return the array match.

Also I do not understand summing into this class. I would sum into Dicegame1 BUT I would remove new int[3] from there.

This are only guide lines. read variables scope, and for loops.